# abort curl download if content type is wrong

Tags: php, curl, content-type

I'm setting up a site where users will be able to post links, and curl (in php) will crawl the url, and format something based on the metadata, open graph tags, etc. I have it set up to run simultaneous uploads with multi_init and multi_exec. I created a gist for the class [here.](https://gist.github.com/kennethrapp/7eb1aa92e5cfb87a599a) What it's supposed to do is:

- get metadata from multiple urls
- return a single json string but only for pages with content-type 'text/html' (so don't bother with direct links to images, js, executables, etc)

The problem seems to be the callback for CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION. I thought that having it return -1 when a content-type header exists but isn't an html header would abort the download but it doesn't seem to do anything (although the check appears correct and it seems to be returning -1.) It still seems to allow any content type through.

Here specifically is the callback:

```
CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($ch, $header){

// if they're sending a content-type header, it must be text/html
 if(stripos(trim($header), "Content-Type") === 0){  

 list($key, $val) = explode(":", $header);

 if(stripos(trim($val), "text/html") === 0){
    return strlen($header);
  }
  else{
    return -1;
  }
}
else{ 
    return strlen($header);
}
}
```

I tried curl_close but got an error about closing curl in a callback. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the callback to set a (global) variable. Skip your `curl_exec()` call when false.

```
$htmlheader = true;
function header_callback($ch, $headers)
{
    $GLOBALS['htmlheader']=false;
}
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,  'header_callback');
if($htmlheader)
{
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}   
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I had to change a couple of things to get it to work with multi_exec (mainly using an array instead of a single global) but that does work, thank you. I updated the gist above with the working version of the class.